# How do I return SELECT SUM() function statement as a value in panel?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to return value instead of object. From the code below l can return value in data grid successfully. But l want to return the value in the code below so that it can be displayed in label or panel as value.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        var query = "Select Sum(Amount) as TotalAmount from OrderDetail";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        SqlDataReader dr;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }               
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can return a single value

```
[HttpGet]
public decimal GetTotalAmount()
{
    var query = "Select Sum(Amount) as TotalAmount from OrderDetail";
    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    decimal totalAmount = 0;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    totalAmount = dr.GetDecimal(0); // Assuming Amount is a decimal type
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    return totalAmount;
}
```

In your view use js fetch to read the totalAmout

If I understood right and u call the api from angular and u already have the dataset set on your first call use

```
dataSet.length
```

for the Total Items

Comment: You can simplify it with ExecuteScalar.